# How to disable a Textfield in Material UI when used with Formik

Tags: material-ui, formik

I have a resulable Material UI textfield that I am using with my formik form -

```
<Fieldname="reportType"
    label="Report Type"
    disabled
    as={TextFieldOutLined}
/>
```

I want to make my `reportType` disabled. When I am passing disabled like above to my `TextFieldOutLined` it is not working.

Below is my `TextFieldOutLined` snippet.

```
const TextFieldOutLined = ({ label, disabled, ...props }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [field] = useField(props);
    return (
        <TextField
            className={classes.formControl}
            {...field}
            {...disabled}
```

Comment: pass disable as true or false and set with your props value. remove {...disabled}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass `disabled={disabled}` to your `TextField` component to disable your `TextField` when the value of `disabled` prop is truthy.

```js
<TextField
    className={classes.formControl}
    {...field}
    disabled={disabled}
```